# Unable to set up transparent background for QDialog rounded corners

Tags: css, pyqt5

This is my Qt5 UI.

[image]

This is Qt5 UI's hierarchy tree.

[image]

The problem is about these rounded corners - they are semi-transparent

On a preview mode of Qt Designer, they're going into darker version.

I'm trying to make them fully transparent, I've done it before and had to deal with similiar issue, only then this was a hierarchy issue (some 'higher' layers were implementing theirs `styleSheet`).

There's my `styleSheet` CSS code:

```
[...]

QDialog 
{
    background: purple;
    border: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 18px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

[...]
```

Comment: Could you describe which corners would you like to make transparent?

Comment: QDialog object corners, so like 40x120 popup window

Comment: @kamil_debski The image you're showing does not reflect the provided stylesheet.

Comment: @musicamante The only thing that I've changed in css provided is ```background```values to make it more readable, there is used ```qlineargradient```

Comment: The fact is that by setting the background for the QDialog you're also setting the background on which draw what's *around* its borders. Instead, you should set a main layout, add a simple container widget, create a further layout for that container to which the actual content will be added and use a proper selector for *that* widget (eg. `QDialog > QWidget { border: ... }`).

Comment: @musicamante Okay, your answer gave me a better view how the actual stylesheet is being drawn - I packed it up in ```QWidget``` but now the ```QDialog``` background is just black

Comment: @kamil_debski Please update your question and provide a valid [mre] of the ui file (and corresponding screenshot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@musicamante

"The fact is that by setting the background for the QDialog you're also setting the background on which draw what's around its borders. Instead, you should set a main layout, add a simple container widget, create a further layout for that container to which the actual content will be added and use a proper selector for that widget (eg. `QDialog > QWidget { border: ... }`)"

```
[...]

QDialog
{
    background: transparent;
}
QDialog > QWidget
{
    background: purple;
    border: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 18px;
}

[...]
```

**NOTE**

I got it black instead of transparent because I had turned off XFCE composition.

When I turned it ON it works as desired and described in this question.